# RD selectfield after ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with a bit of Javascript code. The plugin is

> - @module       RD Mail Form
> - @version      1.1.1
> - @author       Evgeniy Gusarov

I have 2 fields (`select`). The first one `MAKE` and the second `MODEL`.
With AJAX, I select the `MODEL` after choose a `MAKE`.

I don't know how to initialize the field `MODEL` after AJAX because the plugin create above field `<select>`, `<div>`, `<ul>` and `<li>`.

What I need:

After function ajax, on field `MAKE` call a function that initalize field `MODEL`.

```
$("#v_marca_carro").change(function(e) {
    // function ajax - find MODEL from that MAKE --- ITS OK , simple
    $.ajax({ 
    success :  function(response){
            //create field MODEL after filter by MAKE ----IT OK , simple
        }
    }); 

  *****PROBLEM*****
   CALL A FUNCTION LIKE 
   $(#MODEL).rdformMail.initialize();
```

If some one could help, would be appreciated.